# Git stuck on master branch after permissions snafu

Tags: git, centos6

The company I work for has been handed a project that was "fully developed" before we got our hands on it, and we're finding all sorts of neat "features".

After attempting to checkout the master branch without using `sudo` Git has managed to switch to master, but the files that were supposed to be in the other branch are somehow now in master after throwing a few screens worth of errors

`warning: unable to unlink dir/dir/dir/file.php: Permission denied`

When I attempt to check out the feature branch the files came from I get this error

`error: Untracked working tree file 'public/prevoty-php-master/README.md' would be overwritten by merge.`

If I try to run `git stash` I get told by git that there are `No local changes to save`.

I am not a seasoned Git veteran yet, so I'm not sure where to even start.  At this point I'm afraid of doing anything destructive.

What should I do?  Is there a way for me to force Git over to the feature branch?  Should I just remove the files and hope they're saved in the feature branch?

Answer (score 0):

Just spoke with a coworker, we decided to go with `git clean` to purge the untracked files.

We used `git clean  -d  -fx ""`

[Here's the documentation for git-clean](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)